# AWS ssh authentication failed

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have moved an instance from one region to another just doing an AMI on the origin and copying it to the destination. I launched an instance from the AMI on the destination and created a new PEM file when launching the new instance on the destination.

Now I cannot connect to the instance with the new pem file.

```
......
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:8
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: Fl00rfyAdmDev.pem
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

The host and the user which I am trying to connect are right and I am trying to connect as root which I always used to do.

What could be happening?
What can I try?

Thanks

Comment: I have to add that with the old pem file I can access, but not with the new generated with the aws gui console. The aws gui console says that the instance has assigned the new.pem but I only can access with the old.pem. How could I do to change it in order that I can access with the new pem and not the old (the old is the one I used to connect in the other region previous doing an AMI and copying it to the new region)

Comment: 1)What is the command you are using to connect to your instance? 2) What is the filename of your new PEM file? 3) What do you have in your `~/.ssh/config`? 4) Connecting as a root is usually forbidden by default.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your new .pem file is not recognised by ssh. Add the new **.pem** file using the command `ssh-add ~/path/to/pem` on the local machine. Then, try and connect to your ec2 instance using **ssh**.

Answer (score -1):

I had this same issue and couldn't find the answer anywhere. Somehow it seems that simply restarting my computer fixed this issue.